# TypedQuery - createQuery(String) in EntityManager cannot be applied to (String, java.lang.Class<models.Person>)

Tags: java, playframework, persistence, jpa-2.0

I'm currently stuck at the following problem in my Play application:

```
TypedQuery<Person> query = JPA.em().createQuery(
            "SELECT p FROM Person p WHERE p.email = :email AND p.password = :password", Person.class);
query.setParameter("email", email);
query.setParameter("password", password);
```

I keep getting the error:

> method createQuery in interface javax.persistence.EntityManager cannot be applied to given types;
>   required: java.lang.String
>   found: java.lang.String,java.lang.Class
>    reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length

I've compared everything to previous project where I've been using TypedQueries and it seems to be configured correctly. 
My build.sbt:

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
javaJpa.exclude("org.hibernate.javax.persistence", "hibernate-jpa-2.0-api"),
"org.hibernate" % "hibernate-entitymanager" % "4.3.8.Final" 
)
```

In application.conf file:

```
db.default.driver=org.sqlite.JDBC
db.default.url="jdbc:sqlite:db/systemData"
db.default.jndiName=DefaultDS
jpa.default=defaultPersistenceUnit
```

Is there anything I could have skipped?

Comment: Check how are defined the email and password data types in your Person entity. It seems one of them have not the expexted data type: String.

Answer (score 1):

Your code doesn't compile because you probably have an old version of JPA in your classpath, where the method createNamedQuery(String, Class) doesn't exist (see http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html for the documentation of this old version). ie if you are using JPA 1.0 then it wont work
Please check your version of JPA